# Best exercise vs A best exercise

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct ? Explain me.
a  ( or )  b

a/ Walking is good exercise.
b/ Walking is a good exercise.

Comment: Exercise (uncountable noun) = physical activity such as walking, swimming etc:that's what you don't need to use indefinite article "a".you will say,  Walking is good exercise. Secondly, this is good news. You can not say, this is a good news.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct. The correct is "Walking is **the** best exercise".

When a noun is paired with a superlative adjective (like "best", "worst", "oldest", "most interesting"), it takes the definite article "the".

There are some instances where the superlative takes no article, but this is not before nouns, and generally is before things like "when", like "She is happiest when she is playing football", or "she plays best when she is happy". Even in this case, it would be okay to say "she is the happiest" or "she plays the best" instead of "she is happiest"/"she plays best". So with superlatives, use "the", and definitely never use the indefinite article "a".